# Imagen en movimiento

Tags: java, android, xml

¿Cuál es la mejor forma para hacer una imagen en movimiento en Android? He leído que los *GIF* no son recomendables... ¿Entonces cuál sería la mejor opción?
Necesito cargar desde aquí

> .image(R.drawable.ImagenNueva)

Una imagen que tenga movimiento, me da igual que sea un *GIF* o de otra manera, pero que se vayan cambiando las imágenes.

¿Alguna recomendación de cómo podría hacerlo de la mejor manera en Android?

**EDITO:**

Estoy usando el *repositorio*: https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen

Y en mi `clase`:

```
 addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
                .backgroundColor(R.color.fondo)
                .buttonsColor(R.color.boton)
                .image(R.drawable.prueba)
                .title("Texto")
                .description("Texto")
                .build());
```

Desde ahí tengo que cargar la imagen, como me comenta @MiguelAlba lo conocía pero no funciona en este caso ya que desde esta `clase` no cargo la `ImagenView` del `layout` eso se hace desde el repositorio, `clase` del *repositorio* que la carga:

```
public class SlideFragment extends ParallaxFragment {
    private final static String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "background_color";
    private static final String BUTTONS_COLOR = "buttons_color";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String NEEDED_PERMISSIONS = "needed_permission";
    private static final String POSSIBLE_PERMISSIONS = "possible_permission";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 15621;

    private int backgroundColor;
    private int buttonsColor;
    private int image;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String[] neededPermissions;
    private String[] possiblePermissions;

    private TextView titleTextView;
    private TextView descriptionTextView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public static SlideFragment createInstance(SlideFragmentBuilder builder) {
        SlideFragment slideFragment = new SlideFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, builder.backgroundColor);
        bundle.putInt(BUTTONS_COLOR, builder.buttonsColor);
        bundle.putInt(IMAGE, builder.image);
        bundle.putString(TITLE, builder.title);
        bundle.putString(DESCRIPTION, builder.description);
        bundle.putStringArray(NEEDED_PERMISSIONS, builder.neededPermissions);
        bundle.putStringArray(POSSIBLE_PERMISSIONS, builder.possiblePermissions);

        slideFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return slideFragment;
    }

    public static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(String string) {
        return string != null && !string.isEmpty();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide, container, false);
        titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_slide);
        descriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_description_slide);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_slide);
        initializeView();
        return view;
    }

    public void initializeView() {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        backgroundColor = bundle.getInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        buttonsColor = bundle.getInt(BUTTONS_COLOR);
        image = bundle.getInt(IMAGE, 0);
        title = bundle.getString(TITLE);
        description = bundle.getString(DESCRIPTION);
        neededPermissions = bundle.getStringArray(NEEDED_PERMISSIONS);
        possiblePermissions = bundle.getStringArray(POSSIBLE_PERMISSIONS);

        updateViewWithValues();
    }

    public int backgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public int buttonsColor() {
        return buttonsColor;
    }

    public boolean hasAnyPermissionsToGrant() {
        boolean hasPermissionToGrant = hasPermissionsToGrant(neededPermissions);
        if (!hasPermissionToGrant) {
            hasPermissionToGrant = hasPermissionsToGrant(possiblePermissions);
        }
        return hasPermissionToGrant;
    }

    public boolean hasNeededPermissionsToGrant() {
        return hasPermissionsToGrant(neededPermissions);
    }

    public boolean canMoveFurther() {
        return true;
    }

    public String cantMoveFurtherErrorMessage() {
        return getString(R.string.impassable_slide);
    }

    private void updateViewWithValues() {
        titleTextView.setText(title);
        descriptionTextView.setText(description);

        if (image != 0) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), image));
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void askForPermissions() {
        ArrayList<String> notGrantedPermissions = new ArrayList<>();

        if (neededPermissions != null) {
            for (String permission : neededPermissions) {
                if (isNotNullOrEmpty(permission)) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        notGrantedPermissions.add(permission);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (possiblePermissions != null) {
            for (String permission : possiblePermissions) {
                if (isNotNullOrEmpty(permission)) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        notGrantedPermissions.add(permission);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        String[] permissionsToGrant = removeEmptyAndNullStrings(notGrantedPermissions);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissionsToGrant, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean hasPermissionsToGrant(String[] permissions) {
        if (permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (isNotNullOrEmpty(permission)) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousMethodCalls")
    private String[] removeEmptyAndNullStrings(final ArrayList<String> permissions) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(permissions);
        list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que lo que tu quieres es una secuencia de varios fotogramas para crear la sensación de movimiento. Puedes probar a seguir los siguientes pasos:

Agrega todas las imágenes que compongan la secuencia a la carpeta res/drawable.
En ese mismo directorio crea un XML de tipo Resource Type y en su elemento raiz le pones animation-list.
Añade los siguientes item a dicho XML

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen1" android:duration="200"/>
```

y asi con todas las imágenes que tengas.

En el layout de la actividad donde quieras que se muestre la animación añades un ImageView y en su propiedad src le indicas la ruta del archivo con la animación que acabas de crear.

Ahora sólo necesitas indicarle que comience la animación. Para ello primero necesitas una referencia al ImageView

```
ImageView imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.miImagen);
AnimationDrawable animacion = (AnimationDrawable)imagen.getDrawable();
animacion.start();
```

Espero que eso sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: He editado la pregunta @MiguelAlba

Comment: Finalmente no use ese repositorio y si he podido utilizar este método así que marco como útil, gracias !